# Перевод из NSData в NSUrl

Tags: ios

Можно ли каким-то образом перевести `NSData` в `NSUrl`? Это необходимо для создания `AVURLAsset`. В `NSData` хранится аудиофайл.

Пытался сделать следующим способом:

```
NSURL *fileData = [[NSURL alloc] init];
[audioData writeToURL:fileData atomically:YES];
```

Но ничего не происходит, и `fileData` остается пустым.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь нужно указать путь (URL) к файлу, куда сохраняются данные.

```
NSString *filename = @"fileData.dat";
NSURL *fileData = [[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject] URLByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
[audioData writeToURL:fileData atomically:YES];
```

Очень важно получить путь к файлу именно таким казалось бы сложным способом. Но это связано с тем, что писать куда попало в iOS нельзя. В примере используется папка Documents, куда можно писать.

NSURL — это не файл, он не содержит данные файла, это всего-лишь путь к файлу. Чтобы проверить, сохранился ли файл после writeToURL, то нужно открыть папку симулятора, и убедиться, что файл там есть. Или прочитать его программным способом.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!